# <select> population via Ajax: JSON Object vs. echo'ing HTML?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, json

I have a `<select>` element that I need to populate with values I get from an Ajax call. I am debating whether to have the Ajax return a proper JSON object of keys/values or just have it echo out a bunch of `<option>` elements. The options need to be displayed in an alphabetical order in the select.

I feel like using a JSON object is the *proper* way of doing it. But when that object is returned, I have to go through the process of sorting the JSON object by name instead of value. For example:

My PHP returns the following JSON Object response:

```
{"21":"Bandana","18":"Baseball","19":"Cowboy","20":"Trucker"}
```

That is the proper order that I want the items to be displayed in the `<select>` element. But when the Ajax callback gets the JSON Object, it's sorted by key instead of value:

```
{"18":"Baseball","19":"Cowboy","20":"Trucker","21":"Bandana"}
```

So iterating through this JSON object and appending `<option>`'s to the `<select>` will result in the values not being alphabetical. So now, I have to go through the process of sorting this before using it.

Alternatively, if I just throw out the JSON object altogether and just had my PHP do this:

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
    echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
```

Now, back in my Ajax callback all I have to do is append the output to my `<select>` and I'm good to go. Everything is sorted and it works perfectly.

So in the end, I feel like JSON is the **proper way** to do it, but you have to jump through several more hoops to get to the goal. Are there easy JSON Object tricks I'm unaware of? Why would I ever use a JSON Object in this situation if I have to reformat the data in the callback?

Comment: You could also return XML so that you can easily integrate with [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/datalist) in the future.

Comment: The more proper way is to return JSON, because that can provide a RESTful API, so that any kind of service can request the information and receive it in a known format. Maybe you want to write an app that gets the data - I doubt you'll want it in a textual or XML format, but you never know. If this isn't important to you, either is fine. But you have more control over the data if you use JSON - you can store the data somewhere (for some reason), or compare some of it to something else, or whatever. If it's in HTML or XML format, you would need to parse it in some way.

Answer (score 4):

Use a JSON array instead of an object.

```
[{"key": "21", "value":"Bandana"},{"key":"18", "value":"Baseball"},{"key": "19", "value":"Cowboy"},{"key":"20","value":"Trucker"}]
```

Property names of an object aren't maintained in any particular order. That is, when you iterate through the property names of an object with a JavaScript `for ... in` loop, the order is not defined. The runtime system can give you the names in any order; I don't think it's necessarily even repeatable.

Comment: The order is defined (not necessarily what it was when the object was actually defined), but as soon as it is modified, the order won't be the same.

Comment: Is there an easy way to generate a json array in PHP? `json_encode()` generates a JSON Object.

Comment: @Jakobud I don't know PHP so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jakobud: It encodes an array if you pass an array, see the examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php - just take care the array has no keys, because in javascript arrays have no keys.

Comment: @hakre well I have to pass it an array with keys because the keys are `id` values that are used in the `<select>` element... so that won't work.

Comment: You need to create key/value pairs as an object as outlined in this answer and then put each of those into a new array. encode that array and you have what pointy lined out. trivial array operation, if you have no clue, take a look at `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer json with array of arrays. First element as key and second as value.

`[[21,"Bandana"],[18,"Baseball],[19,"Cowboy"],[20,"Trucker"]]`